# Unable to connect to URL with SQLMAP in Mutillidae

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection, sqlmap

I am trying to use SQLMap to study a insertion vulnerability in the Mutillidae 2.8.82 application. The app is installed locally in my Kali Linux 5.17.0-kali3-amd64 running in a virtual machine. However, when I try running SQLMap I only get a few requests rolling before the program terminates with an error:

```
sqlmap -r muti_header.txt --dbms=mysql --dbs -p 'blog_entry' --proxy 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' -vv
...

[14:44:22][14:44:22] [CRITICAL] unable to connect to the target URL or proxy. sqlmap is going to retry the request(s)
[14:44:22] [DEBUG] unable to connect to the target URL or proxy. sqlmap is going to retry the request
[14:44:22] [DEBUG] unable to connect to the target URL or proxy. sqlmap is going to retry the request
[14:44:22] [CRITICAL] unable to connect to the target URL or proxy
```

Here is the content of the 'muti_header.txt' file:

```
POST /mutillidae/index.php?page=add-to-your-blog.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost/mutillidae/index.php?page=add-to-your-blog.php
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 80
Origin: http://localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: language=en; cookieconsent_status=dismiss; welcomebanner_status=dismiss; continueCode=RNJMDy9vxX2pbowKOljEd8BtKTDiL2fyZHK9Syb0YZm6r1az8gq5Pk37BQWL; PHPSESSID=9lun8j8de1335bolvj8svg5tds; showhints=1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1

csrf-token=&blog_entry=qwqweq&add-to-your-blog-php-submit-button=Save+Blog+Entry
```

The funny thing is I am seeing the requests in BURP and they are all answered with a 200 status code, and if I refresh the URL in my browser I can actually see the many SQL queries posted in the page. Nevertheless the program terminates with this error. I've tried using --random-agent and taking out the --proxy option, but it didn't work. Also, the version of mysql is 10.6.7-MariaDB-3.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried some tampers to be sure it is not a WAF ?
Some things to try:
--hex
--random-agent
--drop-set-cookie
--tamper=space2comment,randomcase